# Erro ao tentar cadastrar dados no banco (mysql) via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando inserir alguns dados no banco via php, porem esta me retornando erro, aparentemente esta conectando, não consigo achar um erro na verdade não conheço muito de php, eu fui seguindo tutorial na internet, segue abaixo os códigos.

```js
$(function(){

     var atual_fs, next_fs
     var formulario = $('form[name=formulario]');

     $('.btn-next1').on('click',function (evento) {

      if ($('select , .range').valid()) {
       atual_fs = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
       next_fs = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next();

       atual_fs.hide(500);
       next_fs.show(500);    
      }else {
      }
      evento.preventDefault();

     });

     $('.btn-next').on('click',function (evento){

      var array = formulario.serializeArray();

      $.each(array, function(i, val){
       console.log($.param(array));
      });

      if ($('#name , #email , #telefone').valid()) {
       $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'cadastrar.php',
        data: {cadastrar: 'sim', campos: array},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
         $('#formulario').html('<div class="aguarde"><p> Aguarde estamos requisitando os planos!</p></div>')
        },
        success: function(valor){
         if(valor.erro == 'sim'){
          $('#formulario').html('<div class="erros"><p>'+valor.getErro+'</p></div>');
         }else{
          $('#formulario').html('<div class="ok"><p>'+valor.msg+'</p></div>');
         }
        }
       });

      }else {
       
      }
      evento.preventDefault();

     });

  });
```

```html
<?php 

 sleep(2);
 include_once 'config.php';

 if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST['cadastrar'] == 'sim'):

  $novos_campos = array();
  $campos_post = $_POST['campos'];
  foreach($campos_post as $indice => $valor){
   $novos_campos[$valor['name']] = $valor['value'];
  }

  if(!strstr($novos_campos['email'], '@')){
   $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
   $respostas['getErro'] = 'E-mail Invalido.';  
  }else{
   $respostas['erro'] = 'nao';
   $inserir_banco = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `lead` SET nome = ?, email = ?, telefone = ?, desejo = ?, valor = ?, valores = ?");
   $inserir_sql = array(
    $novos_campos['name'],
    $novos_campos['email'],
    $novos_campos['telefone'],
    $novos_campos['desejo'],
    $novos_campos['valor'],
    $novos_campos['valores']
   );
   if($inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){
    $respostas['erro'] = 'nao';
    $respostas['msg'] = 'Cliente Cadastrado';
   }else{
    $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
    $respostas['getErro'] = 'Erro ao cadastrar.'; 
   }
  }

  echo json_encode($respostas);
 endif;
 ?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=simulador','usuario','senha'); ?>
```

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 então, nao esta cadastrando no banco e me retorna  $respostas['getErro'] = 'Erro ao cadastrar.'; ... Não sei se posso considerar um erro isso, obrigado.

Comment: Retorna o erro do banco, faça assim `$respostas['getErro'] = $inserir_banco->errorInfo();` depois da um `print_r()` no erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque:

```
$inserir_banco->execute($array_sql);
```

Por:

```
$inserir_banco->execute($inserir_sql);
```

Não sei se você notou mas `$array_sql` não foi atribuído em lugar nenhum no seu trecho de código.

Comment: Vlwww deu certo cadastrou, muito obrigado.